# htaccess 301 redirect "works" but I get a 404 error at new site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Sorry for such a long title, but it pretty well describes what is happening.
Details: I have two sites, different domains. Previously, I had a temporary site in a not-visible, but published directory in the older domain. Only those who had the extra directory (or the extra path would normally see the temporary site).

Now that I have a new domain and a permanent new site, I simply want to redirect any attempts to access the old directory/pages/site. Here is the line I added to the old site's htaccess file (last line, BTW):
redirect 301 /mailscamalert.com/weather2/ http://www.mid-southweather.com/

That "works" at least in the sense that the user ends up at the new site. But that site throws up a 404 'flag' and the user ends up at my "erer" page. All the new site's navigation is on that page, of course, but it is probably very confusing!

I've tried removing the trailing "/" on 'weather2/' and/or "...com/", adding 
"index.html" to the new site's url. No change in ending up at the error page. Also have tried "meta" redirects and even a bit of php:
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://www.mid-southweather.com/index.html");

Any helpful suggestions or links, greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your rewrite rule to the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^weather2/ http://www.mid-southweather.com/ [R=301,L]
```

If you had multiple pages in that directory and want them all to redirect to your new target domain, do this:

```
RewriteRule ^weather2/.* http://www.mid-southweather.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Your current rewrite rule appears to append the actual directory you are trying to redirect to the target url.

```
Location: http://mid-southweather.com/weather2/
```

As I discovered using live http headers extension. That weather2 directory of course doesn't exist on your new site, thus the 404.

Just dump your lines and replace them with mine and it should all work nicely. And undo any other changes you may have done in the process of trying to get it working.

Make sure you don't have other rewrite rules going on, it looks to me like you might have one more running somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! My fault for thinking I needed a "redirect" rather than a "rewrite" rule. I'll do some more studying! ;-)